# How to implement "IMMEDIATE" In app update?

Tags: java, android, in-app-update

I have launched application in google play store, for that application i need to implement Immediate In app update, in order to fix the issue who are already using my application

1. I already tried Github examples those are Flexible updates not immediate updates.
2. In android developers site also i have gone through i didnt get proper example

Comment: add a dialog in your app at your launch screen which will ask your users to update the app and if they decline close your app

Comment: Asap application gets open, if update is available, it has force user to update. without update latest version, user should not have right to do further functionalities this is what requirement from the client

Comment: That's exactly what Chirag told you in his answer

Comment: Is there any way to apply immediate in app update which is already in playstore? other than chirag's point of view?

Comment: not that I know

Comment: Okay vivek Mishra...

Answer (score 7):

Try below method for in-app-update for **IMMEDIATE** update of android app.

add below line in apps build gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.6.3'
```

for a better way, place this single method code in your MainActivity and call inside onCreate() method.

```
  AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager;

    private void inAppUpdate() {
    // Creates instance of the manager.
    appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);

    // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
    Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

   // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AppUpdateInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo) {

            Log.e("AVAILABLE_VERSION_CODE", appUpdateInfo.availableVersionCode()+"");
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                    // For a flexible update, use AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE
                    && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
                // Request the update.

                try {
                    appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                            // Pass the intent that is returned by 'getAppUpdateInfo()'.
                            appUpdateInfo,
                            // Or 'AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE' for flexible updates.
                            AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                            // The current activity making the update request.
                            HomeActivity.this,
                            // Include a request code to later monitor this update request.
                            UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ignored) {

                }
            }
        }
    });

    appUpdateManager.registerListener(installStateUpdatedListener);

}
       //lambda operation used for below listener    
    InstallStateUpdatedListener installStateUpdatedListener = installState -> {
             if (installState.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
                 popupSnackbarForCompleteUpdate();
             } else
              Log.e("UPDATE", "Not downloaded yet");
         };


    private void popupSnackbarForCompleteUpdate() {

    Snackbar snackbar =
            Snackbar.make(
                    findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                    "Update almost finished!",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
       //lambda operation used for below action
    snackbar.setAction(this.getString(R.string.restart), view -> 
               appUpdateManager.completeUpdate());
    snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
    snackbar.show();
}
```

courtsey [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates)

Comment: In conjunction with @Dhiren answer, one should also handle the case for update getting stalled by using UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS state.

Comment: Sure, can you please share chunk line of code with `UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS` or share any link so others can get your comment easily.

Comment: For reference, code is there on the link you have shared already. This is the section url : https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates#immediate_flow

Answer (score 1):

We are using below scenario in our app for Mandatory updates.

We are maintain Current version code and latest version code in our backend database.

- In Splash screen, I am calling that API to check latest version code.
- Get current version code from APP.
- Get latest version code from API.
- If latest version code is incremental then current. We Display Update Dialog.
- You have to make sure that, Once new update rollout you need to change version in backend database.

Comment: This is just a basic conditions, Have you used any API in this Application?

Comment: My application already in playstore live. for that application how to implement Immediate update without intent to playstore?

Comment: As far I know, for live version you can not do that things. For future use, you can follow above steps.

Comment: Thankyou Chirag,..but its possible for live version too.

Comment: Okay. Share it if you found something.